# Bind asp.net control (Label -or- TextBox) to property in code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, code-behind

I have a dynamically TextBox at the code behind (asp.net control).
I want to bind the text of it with a string variable (kept also at the C# code behind), to do that at the JavaScript I just set it with the '%<' stuff, but how do I do that at the C# code so the TextBox will be automatically set with the new value of the property at each time the property changes?

Thanks!

Comment: Why does the sting variable update? I would imagine I would update the textbox the same place the string variable is updated in the code behind like textBox.Text = stringVariable;

Comment: Because there is a way of binding some control (Label, TextBox etc.) via the '<%# properyAtCodeBehind %>' so the text of the control will be changed accordingly after calling the Page.Bind() Method so my question is how to set the binding ('<%# ItemId %>') at the C# code behind. Generally I would prefer to have a proper answer and not questions about why.. Thanks in advance.